# Do I need to malloc C-style strings?

Tags: arduino, c-strings

I recently started using Arduino so I still have to adapt and find the differences between C/C++ and the Arduino language.

So I have a question for you.

When I see someone using a C-style string in Arduino (`char *str`), they always initialize it like this (and never free it) :

```
char *str = "Hello World";
```

In pure C, I would have done something like this:

```
int my_strlen(char const *str)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (str[i]) {
        i++;
    }
    return (i);
}

char *my_strcpy(char *dest, char const *src)
{
    char *it = dest;

    while (*src != 0) {
        *it = *src;
        it++;
        src++;
    }
    return (dest);
}

char *my_strdup(char const *s)
{
    char *result = NULL;
    int length = my_strlen(s);

    result = my_malloc(sizeof(char const) * (length + 1));
    if (result == NULL) {
        return (NULL);
    }
    my_strcpy(result, s);
    return (result);
}
```

and then initialize it like this:

```
char *str = my_strdup("Hello World");
my_free(str);
```

So here is my question, on C-style Arduino strings, is malloc optional or these people just got it wrong?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: FYI you may get a good response on this site: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In a memory-constrained device like the 328P for example, you should try to NEVER allocate strings.  Dynamic memory allocation on devices this small is a recipe for disaster.  Source: 15 years of experience and 10 hardware patents.  Know your device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ it's better to use `new[]`/`delete[]` and not mix it with `malloc`/`free`.

In the Arduino there is also String class, that hides those allocations from you.

However using dynamic memory allocations in such restrained platform has its pitfalls, like heap fragmentation (mainly because String overloads + operator, so everyone is overusing it like: `Serial.println(String{"something : "} + a + b + c + d + ......)` and then wonders about mysterious crashes.

More about it on Majenko's blog: [The Evils of Arduino String class](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/) (Majenko has highest reputation on the arduino stackexchange)

Basically with the String class your strdup code would be simple as this:

```
 String str{"Hello World"};
 String copyOfStr = str;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just read the article. He doesn't explain why he doesn't malloc the string so I still don't understand why, but if he is a professional, it must work like this.

But It's strange, in pure C that would have given me a segfault and I don't understand why it is not the case in Arduino.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, there is no restriction to it. There are just recommendation that it's not a great idea to do it. Only NO-NO is using malloc to allocate objects with nontrivial constructors (only POD structs can be allocated by malloc). That's because new also calls constructor(s) on newly created objects